# How to get the List name that is in a list - python

Tags: python

I have lots of lists for example:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['1', '2', '3']
group = [List, List2]
```

My question now is, how can I get the **name** of the list where "a" is in. Is it even possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean `group = [list, list2]`? Remember that Python is case sensitive.

Comment: Ops, I have committed myself. Yeah I mean that :D thanks.

Comment: Also what are you trying to do this? Why do you need the names of the original lists? Likely there is another, more pythonic solution to your original problem that you are trying to solve with this.

Comment: Pro tip: Don't use `list` as a variable name. Python has a builtin type with the name `list` already.

Comment: Yeah, it's just an example :D

Answer (score 5):

Variable names are not typically available at run time. In other words, `group` has no idea of the names of the variables to the lists that were used to create it.

Depending on the original problem you are trying to solve here, you might want to use a dictionary instead. This will allow you to assign a name to each list:

```
group = {
   'list1': list1,
   'list2': list2,
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you, but it's not python.. but can python grab it from json's?

Comment: that is definetely python

Comment: you should familiarize yourself w/ dictionaries @DaveReiß

Comment: @DaveReiß Python dictionaries are very similar to JSON objects. They both are implementations of a data structure that stores (key, value) pairs. There are some differences in syntax, however. For example, the keys of a dictionary can be any hashable value, not just a string. Also, strings are allowed to have single quotes in python but required to have double quotes in JSON.

Answer (score 3):

Further expanding in @Code-Apprentices implementation:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['1', '2', '3']
group = {
   'list1': list1,
   'list2': list2,
}
for i in group.keys():
    if "a" in group[i]:
      print(i)
```

this will print `list1`

Comment: Okay thanks that worked, I didn't know about the dictionaries. Thank's